# Inserting in List of lists using Array.asList in java

Tags: java

I am coding in java and i have three arrays also i have a List of lists.

```
int[] recovery=bl.generateRecovery();
    int[] periods = bl.generatePeriods(recovery);
    int[] deadlines =  bl.generateDeadlines(periods);

    List<List<Integer>>temp=new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

Now i want to add the arrays as lists in the list.

I tried using:

```
temp.add(Arrays.asList(recovery));
```

But it failed. 
Can someone tell me how to do it ??

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.asList(recovery)` will give you a `List<int[]>` object, not `List<Integer>`. Try using `Integer[] recovery` instead.

Edit:
You might want to have your methods like `generateRecovery` etc. to return `List<Integer>` instead of `int[]`. Arrays are not flexible and it is usually better to use `List`.

Comment: [Not mandatorily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47244534/1746118) I would say, though good to be clean in API implementation contracts.

Comment: @nullpointer Yes, I know. I am just trying to state the problem in the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A) on `int[]` [`boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--) and collected as `List` as:

```
temp.add(Arrays.stream(recovery).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fusion two different types (int[] and ArrayList<>).
They are not the same, you have to unify your arrays to one of the types.

```
    int[] recovery= {1,2,3};

    List<int[]>temp=new ArrayList<>();

    temp.add(recovery);

    System.out.println(temp.get(0)[1]);
```

This code prints a 2.